# Is "up to" a preposition?

Tags: grammar, prepositions

Is "up to" a preposition?

Example sentence: **You can set up to 70%**
Also is it the object of the sentence? Or it acts as prepositional phrase that modifies "set"?

Comment: Could you give us some more context, or a more complete sentence?

Comment: This is unclear - 70% of what?

Comment: Yes, "up to" is a preposition phrase functioning as a determiner in the noun phrase "up to 70%" which is the direct object of "set".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think it's likely, that "up to 70%" would be classified as a prepositional phrase that modifies "set".  Is there a particular reason you need to know?

It is not the object of the sentence.  This sentence is an [ellipsis](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/ellipsis) with the direct object omitted.  The full sentence would include the direct object:

> You can set **(the value)** up to 70%

As written, you'd have to already know the direct object from previous context.

You can also argue that, "you can set up to 70%," is a *sentence fragment* and not a complete sentence.  At the least, it should include some pronoun like "it":

> You can set **it** up to 70%.

It's not wrong to speak in sentence fragments, although it can be confusing for the listener. Written English, however, should include only complete sentences -- except of course when writing creative prose, poetry, dialogue, and any other time the writer doesn't feel like it.

[Edit]  Apparently this is incorrect.  I'm just going to reprint BillJ's answer:

> The bracketed element is a noun phrase functioning as object of “set”.
>
> 70% is called a ‘fused-head partitive’ construction where 70% is a noun whose of PP complement is missing but can be represented by "x": “You can set up to 70% of x”, where the meaning of "x" is retrievable form the context.
>
> The crucial point is that the preposition phrase “up to” is a determiner in the noun phrase “up to 70% (of x)” functioning as object of "set".

Comment: Sorry, Andrew, but I wouldn't go along with that -- please see my answer.

Comment: @BillJ  no worries, I figured someone with more linguistic know-how would correct me if I'm wrong.  Is there anything accurate in my answer or is it completely off-base?

Comment: It's a shame really, as it's a nicely crafted answer, and it got the green tick from the OP. Could you edit it perhaps?

Answer (score 2):

> *You can set* [*up to 70%*].

The bracketed element is a noun phrase functioning as object of “set”.

70% is called a ‘fused-head partitive’ construction where 70% is a noun whose *of* PP complement is missing but can be represented by "x": “You can set up to 70% of x”, where the meaning of "x" is retrievable form the context.

The crucial point is that the preposition phrase “up to” is a determiner in the noun phrase “up to 70% (of x)” functioning as object of "set".